Laravel join relation from Mongo database connection via model
I'm working through a Laravel 11 project that uses a default MySQL8 database. I have a secondary database connection that's MongoDB that's being used as an archive database for cold storage data.
I have an ArchiveRecord model in my project that pulls from an archive_records table within MySQL, and it contains a record_id column which stores the equivalent MongoDB object id.
I'm using the laravel-mongodb package v5 and would like to join the MongoDB document to my ArchiveRecord document, but I'm getting null, what am I missing?
ArchiveRecord:
/**
 * Get the planet
 */
public function planet()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Planet::class, 'record_id', 'id');
}

And my Planet model, it's called Planet temporarily:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Planet extends Eloquent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $table = 'applications';
    protected $primaryKey = '_id';
}

Outputs:
{
    "model": {
        "id": "01jafvbbcvdcq8mkf73abmn2hm",
        "record_id": "67125bd4e5e0d0e7650179b2",
        "company_id": 1,
        "status": "complete",
        "status_metadata": null,
        "record_connection": "mongodb",
        "record_table": "applications",
        "archiveable_type": "App\\Models\\Application",
        "archiveable_id": 12730,
        "archiveable_relations": [
            "affiliate",
            "affiliateCampaign",
            "affiliateProduct",
            "affiliateProduct.splits",
            "affiliateProduct.splits.splitAffiliate",
            "affiliateProduct.splits.commissionEntry",
            "apiRequestLog",
            "commissions",
            "country",
            "hash",
            "hashes",
            "lastKnownPingtreeBuyerTransaction",
            "modelable",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransaction",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransaction.buyer",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransaction.buyerTier",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransactions",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransactions.buyer",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransactions.buyerTier",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransactions.buyerTier.buyer",
            "pingtreeBuyerTransactions.buyerTier.options",
            "pingtreeGroup",
            "pingtreeSelected",
            "product",
            "redirect",
            "redirect.affiliate",
            "redirect.affiliateCampaign",
            "redirect.buyer",
            "redirect.buyerTier",
            "redirect.buyerTier.buyer"
        ],
        "additional_metadata": null,
        "additional_fields": null,
        "failed_at": null,
        "archived_at": "2024-10-18T13:00:04.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2024-10-18T12:58:56.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-10-18T13:00:04.000000Z",
        "planet": null
    }
}

